ROS 2 foxy unbale to locate package
the problem is here
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-foxy-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ros-dev-tools is already the newest version (1.0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

anyway i've installed ros2 humble
`
